# select columns from the files and save the output

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, awk

i am new to the programming.I have many files in a directory as shown below: and each file consists of two column data.

```
TS.TST_X.1990-11-22
TS.TST_Y.1990-11-22
TS.TST_Z.1990-11-22

TS.TST_X.1990-12-30
TS.TST_Y.1990-12-30
TS.TST_Z.1990-12-30
```

At first i want to choose only second columns of all files having same name( only difference in X,Y,Z strings)(TS.TST_X.1990-11-22,TS.TST_Y.1990-11-22,TS.TST_Z.1990-11-22) and want to save the output In a file like TSTST19901112

Similarly for (TS.TST_X.1990-12-30,TS.TST_Y.1990-12-30,TS.TST_Z.1990-12-30 )files also and want to save the output like TSTST19901230

For example:
if files contains like as below

```
TS.TST_X.1990-11-22                 TS.TST_Y.1990-11-22               TS.TST_Z.1990-11-22
1  2                                 1   3.4                          1    2.1
2  5                                 2   2.4                          2    4.2
3  2                                 3   1.2                          3    1.0
4  4                                 4   2.4                          4    3.5
5  8                                 5   6.3                          5    1.8
```

Then output file TSTST19901122 would be like

```
2   3.4    2.1
5   2.4    4.2
2   1.2    1.0
4   2.4    3.5
8   6.3    1.8
```

i tried the code

```
#!/bin/sh
for file in /home/min/data/*
do
awk '{print $2}' $file 
done
```

But my written code only reads the column of all files doesn't give expected output.So here i need experts help.

Comment: Do you use `sh` or `bash`? `sh` ([Bourne-shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell)) is usally not `bash` ([Bourne-again shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell))).

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for showing your attempts in form of code. Could you please do let us know if you want to compare the 1st column of all files and compare them for values? Or we could simply concatenate files without checking 1st field? Kindly confirm once

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 i donot need first coulmn at all..

Comment: @glkshu, I didn't mention about needing them in output. I meant do you want to compare 1st column values from file to file? Like line 1 of file1 has 1 in 1dt column and line 2 of file2 has 2 in 1st column, in rat case they should be concatenated?

Comment: no sir i donot need

Comment: Does the order of columns in output file matter?

Comment: Yes it matter @KamilCuk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Since OP has mentioned in comments that actual file names are little different so adding solution as per that here(since as per OP only 3 type of files with different year and month are there)..

```
for file in TS.TST_BHE*
do
      year=${file/*\./}
      year=${year//-/}
      yfile=${file/BHE/BHN}
      zfile=${file/BHE/BHZ}
      outfile="TSTST.$year"
      ##echo $file $yfile $zfile
      paste "$file" "$yfile" "$zfile"  | awk '{print $2,$4,$6}' > "$outfile"
done
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
for file in TS.TST_BHE*
##Going through TS.TST_BHE named files in for loop here, where variable file will have its name in it.
do
      year=${file/*\./}
      ##Creating year where removing everything till . here.
      year=${year//-/}
      ##Substituting all - with null in year variable.
      yfile=${file/BHE/BHN}
      ##Substituting BHE with BHN in file variable and saving it to yfile here.
      zfile=${file/BHE/BHZ}
      ##Substituting BHE with BHZ in file variable and saving it to zfile here.
      outfile="TSTST.$year"
      ##Creating outfile which has TSTST. with year variable value here.
      ##echo $file $yfile $zfile
      paste "$file" "$yfile" "$zfile"  | awk '{print $2,$4,$6}' > "$outfile"
      ##using paste to contenate values of 3 of the files(BHE BHN and BHZ) and printing only 2nd, 4th and 6th fields out of it.
done
```

---

---

Could you please try following, based on comment of OP that we could simply concatenate Input_files without checking 1st column's value.

```
for file in TS.TST_X*
do
      year=${file/*\./}
      year=${year//-/}
      yfile=${file/X/Y}
      zfile=${file/X/Z}
      outfile="TSTST.$year"
      ###echo $file $yfile $zfile ##Just to print variable values(optional)
      paste "$file" "$yfile" "$zfile"  | awk '{print $2,$4,$6}' > "$outfile"
done
```

For showing samples output will be as follows, above will generate file name d `TS.TST_X.19901122` for shown samples.

```
cat TSTST.19901122
2 3.4 2.1
5 2.4 4.2
2 1.2 1.0
4 2.4 3.5
8 6.3 1.8
```

Answer (score 4):

Hope below example help you to start with, next time when you post in SO make sure you post input properly so that it will be easy for readers to help you:

Here is online :  <kbd>[**DEMO**](https://repl.it/join/ahgkoffy-akshayhegde)</kbd>

```
[akshay@db1 tmp]$ cat test.sh 
#!/usr/bin/env bash 

# use sort and uniq where field sep being dot, 
# we get unique date
while IFS= read -r f; do 

    # creates veriable like TS.TST_*.1990-11-22
    i=$(sed 's/_[^.]/_*/' <<<"$f"); 

    # modify outfile if you want any extension suffix etc
    outfile=$(sed 's/[^[:alnum:]]//g' <<<"$i")".txt";


    # filename expansion with unquoted variable
    # finally use awk to print whatever you want

    paste $i | awk 'NR>1{for(i=2; i<=NF; i+=2)printf "%s%s", $(i), (i<NF ? OFS : ORS)}' >"$outfile"

done < <(printf '%s\n' TS.TST* | sort -t'.' -u -nk3)

[akshay@db1 tmp]$ bash test.sh 
[akshay@db1 tmp]$ cat TSTST19901122.txt 
2  3.4  2.1
5  2.4  4.2
2  1.2  1.0
4  2.4  3.5
8  6.3  1.8
```

**Input:**

```
[akshay@db1 tmp]$ ls TS.TST* -1
TS.TST_X.1990-11-22
TS.TST_Y.1990-11-22
TS.TST_Z.1990-11-22

[akshay@db1 tmp]$ for i in TS.TST*; do cat "$i"; done
TS.TST_X.1990-11-22 
1  2               
2  5              
3  2             
4  4          
5  8           
TS.TST_Y.1990-11-22
1   3.4
2   2.4
3   1.2
4   2.4
5   6.3
TS.TST_Z.1990-11-22
1    2.1
2    4.2
3    1.0
4    3.5
5    1.8
```

Comment: Copy/paste that into http://shellcheck,net and it'll tell you about some of the issues. One it might not tell you about is that `for f in $(ls TS.TST* | ...); do ...; done` should be `while IFS= read -r f; do ... done < <(printf '%s\n' TS.TST* | ...)` or similar ( or better :-) ! ).

Comment: Thank you, I will correct once I am back to my system. Now on mobile

Comment: @EdMorton modified as you suggested, however I still have unquoted variable

Answer (score 1):

The following recreation of input files:

```
cat <<EOF >TS.TST_X.2000-11-22 
1  2               
2  5              
3  2             
4  4          
5  8       
EOF
cat <<EOF >TS.TST_Y.2000-11-22
1   3.4
2   2.4
3   1.2
4   2.4
5   6.3
EOF
cat <<EOF >TS.TST_Z.2000-11-22
1    2.1
2    4.2
3    1.0
4    3.5
5    1.8
EOF

cat <<EOF >TS.TST_X.1990-11-22 
1  2               
2  5              
3  2             
4  4          
5  8       
EOF
cat <<EOF >TS.TST_Y.1990-11-22
1   3.4
2   2.4
3   1.2
4   2.4
5   6.3
EOF
cat <<EOF >TS.TST_Z.1990-11-22
1    2.1
2    4.2
3    1.0
4    3.5
5    1.8
EOF
```

[When run with the following script on repl](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/MurkyPopularBytes#main.sh):

```
# get the filenames
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "TS.TST*" -printf "%f\n" |
# meh, sort them, so it looks nice
sort |
# group files according to suffix after the dot
awk -F. '
    { a[$3]=a[$3]" "$0 }
    END{ for (i in a) print i, a[i] }
' |
# here we have: YYYY-MM-DD  filename1 filename2 filename3
# let's transform it into TSTSTYYYYMMDD filename{1,2,3}
sed -E 's/^([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})/TSTST\1\2\3/' |
while IFS=' ' read -r new f1 f2 f3; do
    # get second column from all files
    # if your awk doesn't sort files, they would have to be sorted here
    paste "$f1" "$f2" "$f3" | awk '{print $2,$4,$6}' > "$new"
done

# just output
for i in TSTST*; do echo "$i"; cat "$i"; done
```

Generates the following output:

```
TSTST19901122
2 3.4 2.1
5 2.4 4.2
2 1.2 1.0
4 2.4 3.5
8 6.3 1.8
TSTST20001122
2 3.4 2.1
5 2.4 4.2
2 1.2 1.0
4 2.4 3.5
8 6.3 1.8
```

I would advise to do research on basic shell commands. Read documentation about `find`. Read an introduction into `awk` and `sed` scripting. Read a good introduction into bash, get to know how to iterate, sort, merge and filter list of files in bash. And also read [how to read a stream line by line](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).